# How should I create Mongoose Schema for Form Checkboxes in React?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-hook-form, react-fullstack

I am creating a Form in React, using MUI and react-hooks-form and I cannot seem to make a successful POST request to my endpoint because something between what I am sending through my form and what Mongoose Schema should receive is not working.  When I log the data, my checkbox values are log as an array and I have that checkbox group as an array of strings. Always Bad Requests. Hope someone can help me out.

User Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Por favor escribe tu nombre"],
    maxLength: [60, "El nombre no puede tener mas de 50 caracteres"],
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Por favor indicanos tu email"],
  },
  form: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["form1", "form2", "form3"],
  },
  pattern: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"],
  },
  gadgets: [String],
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

React Form (Not Refactored yet)

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";

const Form: FC = (): ReactElement => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/api/users", {
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        age: data.age,
        form: data.form,
        pattern: data.pattern,
        gadgets: data.gadgets,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 201 || 200) {
          setValue("name", "");
          setValue("email", "");
          setValue("age", "");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      sx={{}}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="on"
    >
      <Box component="div" sx={{ margin: "30px 0 30px 10px" }}>
        <Typography variant="body1">Datos Personales</Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{ m: 3, display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}
      >
        <TextField
          {...register("name", { required: true })}
          aria-invalid={errors.name ? "true" : "false"}
          size="small"
          id="name"
          label="Nombre Completo"
          variant="outlined"
          name="name"
          type="string"
          sx={{ width: "40ch" }}
        />
        {errors.name?.type === "required" && (
          <p role="alert">Name is required</p>
        )}
        <TextField
          {...register("email", { required: true })}
          aria-invalid={errors.email ? "true" : "false"}
          size="small"
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          sx={{ width: "40ch" }}
        />
        {errors.email?.type === "required" && (
          <p role="alert">Email is required</p>
        )}
        <TextField
          {...register("age", { required: true })}
          aria-invalid={errors.age ? "true" : "false"}
          size="small"
          id="age"
          label="Edad"
          variant="outlined"
          name="age"
          type="number"
          sx={{ width: "10ch" }}
        />
        {errors.age?.type === "required" && <p role="alert">Age is required</p>}
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{
          m: 10,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel id="demo-form-control-label-placement" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
            Por favor Elija la Forma
          </FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-labelledby="demo-form-control-label-placement"
            name="form"
            defaultValue="top"
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
            }}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("form")}
              value="form1"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Forma 1"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("form")}
              value="form2"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Forma 2"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("form")}
              value="form3"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Forma 3"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <FormLabel
            id="demo-form-control-label-placement"
            sx={{ mb: 3, mt: 3 }}
          >
            Por favor Elija la Tela
          </FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-labelledby="demo-form-control-label-placement"
            name="pattern"
            defaultValue="top"
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
            }}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("pattern")}
              value="pattern1"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Tela 1"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("pattern")}
              value="pattern2"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Tela 2"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("pattern")}
              value="pattern3"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Tela 3"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        {/* <FormControl>
          <FormLabel
            id="demo-form-control-label-placement"
            sx={{ mb: 3, mt: 3 }}
          >
            Por favor Elija los Accesorios
          </FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-labelledby="demo-form-control-label-placement"
            name="gadgets"
            defaultValue="top"
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
            }}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("gadgets")}
              value="gadget1"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Accesorio 1"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("gadgets")}
              value="gadget2"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Accesorio 2"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              {...register("gadgets")}
              value="gadget3"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Accesorio 3"
              labelPlacement="top"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl> */}
        <FormLabel id="demo-form-control-label-placement" sx={{ mb: 3, mt: 3 }}>
          Por favor Elija los Accesorios
        </FormLabel>
        <FormGroup
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-around",
          }}
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            {...register("gadgets")}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="Accesorio 1"
            sx={{ mb: 3 }}
            name="gadgets"
            value="gadget1"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            {...register("gadgets")}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="Accesorio 2"
            sx={{ mb: 3 }}
            name="gadgets"
            value="gadget2"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            {...register("gadgets")}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="Accesorio 3"
            sx={{ mb: 3 }}
            name="gadgets"
            value="gadget3"
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{ m: 10, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <Button variant="contained" type="submit">
          Enviar
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

API Handler

```
import dbConnect from "../../../utils/dbConnect";
import User from "../../../models/User";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  await dbConnect();

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const users = await User.find(
          {}
        ); /* find all the data in our database */
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      try {
        const user = await User.create(
          req.body
        ); /* create a new model in the database */
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: user });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      break;
  }
}
```

LOGGED DATA
[image: LoggedData Fronm Submit]

AXIOS ERROR
[image: Axios Error]

I tried reading Mongoose Docs, searching for videos on youtube. Several posts here in Stack Overflow and I cannot seem to get it.

Comment: are you receiving some data in your `console.log(data)`? and what is the error message you receive in the API call . and also can you add your code of your (`post route for User model`)

Comment: Hi @MelCarloIguis! Thanks for answering. I just updated the post with your requests.